# Centering a div with absolute positioning

Tags: css, html, center, css-position

I know this has probably been asked a million times, but how do I center a div that has absolute positioning.

I have tried this and it does not center it.

You can view the site [here](http://goodmorningmoon.ca) password:springy88

```
#logo{ position:absolute; width:243px; left: 50%; margin-left: 121.5px; }
```

Comment: Just as an FYI. There are no half pixels. Pixel measurements can only be whole numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `negative margins` - `margin-left:-121px`. That will center the logo. After that you'll need to properly position your nav...

Answer (score 8):

Centering a div is very easy of you know the width and height of the Div. 
Assuming that your div has 100width and 100 Height

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top;50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    margin-top:-50px;
}
```

if you are not sure about the dimentions , then probably you can go for a jquery method.

Answer (score -1):

You could set the % value half of 50%, ie: left: 25% or right: 25%; Providing the wrapper is twice the width of the element.

[Test Here..](http://jsfiddle.net/gYXG5/1/)